# While running from MAC writing on a appgroup path is working fine on ipad, but its not working when creating ipa & installing on ipad

Tags: xcode, debugging, release, ipa

It seems to be  entitlement issue while creating the ipa though different build process than debug.

AppGroup added in entitlements file of the app. And writing to this appgroup path isn't working in while using ipa installation but works in debug mode running from the xcode.

But we are using only 1 entitlement file for both debug and release. Please find the screenshots.[image]

[image]
I am trying to copy or write file on the below path:

```
NSURL *appGroupUrl =  [[NSFileManager defaultManager]     containerURLForSecurityApplicationGroupIdentifier:@"group.com.myorg.myapp"];
    NSString *appGroupUrlPath = appGroupUrl.path;
```

But copying or writing on the above path isn't working in release mode but works fine in debug mode.

What can be the reason for this different behavior for debug mode vs release mode?

Comment: I would recommend to post your code hat shows different behaviour between debug and release inline to your question and not as picture and maybe additionally the example result for debug and release.

Comment: @MarkusEgle Thanks for Your response. I edited the question now.

Comment: If it's release issue then double check 1. the "app groups" enabled for production in the AppId (from web console) and 2. the provisioning profile used for release is correct one.